# PHP Upload image to mysql database using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a database set up and am trying to upload an image to it. The database is called 'blob' and has 3 fields. id, name and image, with image set as blob. When trying to upload the image i get an error that i am unsure of. Below is my code.

```
<?php
include ("dbConnect.php");
?>

<form action="imageuploadtest.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="image" type="file"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

  $imageName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  $imageData = file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
  $imageType = $_FILES["image"]["type"];

  if(substr($imageType,0,5)=="image")
  {
     $dbQuery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blob ( name, image) VALUES ('$imageName', '$imageData')");
     $dbQuery->execute();
  }
  else
  {
   echo "only images are allowed";
  } 
}
?>
```

The database connection is fine, but i get the following error message that i am usure of how to fix.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters' in N:\ftp\compc\d12ac1\FlightsFromNI\imageuploadtest.php:23 Stack trace: #0 N:\ftp\compc\d12ac1\FlightsFromNI\imageuploadtest.php(23): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO blo...') #1 {main} thrown in N:\ftp\compc\d12ac1\FlightsFromNI\imageuploadtest.php on line 23.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Have now changed my table name from blob to imgupload but still get the same error message?

Comment: `blob` is a reserved word in mysql. You'll have to enclose your table name in backticks. It's better to avoid using reserved words as table or column names all together.

Comment: you are not using `PDO` correctly and are subject to SQL injections in the manner in which you are using it.

Comment: and if you really want to use "blob" as your table name then change it in your query to "INSERT INTO \`blob\`..."

Comment: To all ^ - I had my answer prepared about 4.5 mins ago prior to this comment, and wanted to make sure that was the case and researched it before I hit the "Post answer" button ;-) My answer was not pulled from comments.

Comment: Thanks but i have renamed my table to imgupload and am still getting the same error. Anyone know why? or how to fix it?

Comment: Does your filename contain any character that MySQL would complain about, such as a hyphen, a space etc.? From http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php *"MySQL will return an error if a named placeholder has a hyphen in it:"* It's for placeholders but the same could be true for filenames.

Comment: Plus, you are indeed using PDO to connect with, right? Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` also and tell me what you get.

Comment: I suggest you also try `$dbQuery = $db->query` instead of `$dbQuery = $db->prepare` since you're not "preparing" anything.

Comment: Got it working using the suggestion from @JerzySkalski

Comment: That's great, glad to hear it.

Comment: Nota: It's usually best to store files in folders and make a reference to the file, rather than storing binary data in a table. This will eventually dramatically increase your database size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about blob. It's about binary data. Try to use that line (but it may also not work):

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO blob ( name, image) VALUES ('$imageName', " . $db->quote($imageData) . ")");
```

Also your query is not SAFE (for hackers), you should be sanitizing all input to your database. PDO has great support for *prepared statements*.

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Will also look into making the query safer.

Answer (score 4):

`blob` is a MySQL reserved word

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either rename your table to something else, or use ticks around it:

```
INSERT INTO `blob` ...
```

---

Nota: It's usually best to store files in folders and make a reference to the file, rather than storing binary data in a table. This will eventually dramatically increase your database size.